# App crashes if Activity starts portrait Mode

Tags: android

I have Android Studio 2.3 bet 3, somehow my application is behaving strangely. If the `activity` starts in portrait mode it crashes straight a way. But if it starts in landscape mode it does well even if i rotate to portrait mode.

Here are the crash logs.but same XML file line and error comes for all activities.

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.activity.VisitsActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #43: Error inflating class android.support.v7.widget.ActionBarContextView
```

Comment: It says that you have a some bug in your XML.

Comment: Try cleaning the project.

Comment: I have clean and build project many times @Anix  Anix PasBesoin

Comment: @A.A. it says for all screens if i starts activity in portrait mode, but i has no issue if i rotate screen then it works in both modes. This app was working fine since 2 years , suddenly it is showing this issue.

Comment: I have found the solution, dimen.xml for portrait doesn't have some values which are defined in landscape dimen.xml. that's why it crashes in portrait mode.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

dimen.xml for portrait doesn't have some values which are defined in landscape dimen.xml. that's why it crashes in portrait mode